# CSS Validator Complains About justify-content and -webkit-animation

Tags: css, validation, css-grid, justify

[image]I have a website using CSS Grids and when validating the website via https://www.w3.org/ it gives me several errors. Why is this? I thought justify-self was normal CSS according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self?

Thank you!

Comment: It could be because `space-evenly` and `justify-self` are properties from [the CSS Box Alignment Module Level 3 spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/) which still has a 'working draft' status (and btw. I wouldn't recomment using them in production yet, because support still isn't good yet  )

Comment: In plain English, these values are still experimental and have not achieved enough status in the W3C to be included in their validator. However, browser makers, who operate independently, can implement properties and values whenever they want. See the duplicate for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It is because it is not yet updated to support new spec because it is not officially released I think, I had same issue as you did even tho spec itself is baked in into browsers. The following snippet does validate but only with prefixes.

```
div {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

While this does not. Short answer is because it is [Working Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#propdef-justify-self)

```
div {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    justify-self: end;

}
```